# Anaconda jupyter notebook

Tags: anaconda, jupyter

I installed Anaconda & Python following this guide:
http://jupyter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html
version installed: 3.4

Now the problem is I can access the jupyter notebook via http://localhost:8888/tree
but i cannot access it via the internet ip address
Note, I am using a AWS EC2 instance.

What might be the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access your notebook server remotely via a web browser, you must do the following at a minimum:

1. Create a custom profile for the notebook
2. Edit the file ipython_notebook_config.py for the custom profile
3. Start the notebook with the profile just created

Please consult the IPython.org's documentation for the details.
http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/1/interactive/public_server.html

Answer (score 0):

There's another way to start Jupyter notebook server which is embedded in Continuum Anaconda, Here's the command. You can override some parameter like port, server, --no-browser, etc while starting the server .

```
/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda/bin/python  /opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda/bin/jupyter-notebook  --port=8998 --ip=0.0.0.0 --no-browser
```